# Getting "No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop." error when running makefile. What does it mean?

Tags: linux, webcam

I'm trying to get a webcam working with my Raspberry Pi
[How do I install webcam firmware on the Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5111/how-do-i-install-webcam-firmware-on-the-raspberry-pi)

I found a possible way of doing this with gspca.

So I downloaded the file and unzipped it.
http://moinejf.free.fr/gspca-2.15.19.tar.gz

I followed the instructions in this answer (replacing with my version number 3.6.11+)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1304/3027

And now I'm trying to run the makefile that I unzipped but I get this error and my googling has been fruitless so far.

```
root@WebCamEthernet:/home/pi/Downloads/gspca-2.15.19# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.6.11+/build M=/home/pi/Downloads/gspca-2.15.19/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.6.11+/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.6.11+/build'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Here is the makefile.

```
KVER=$(shell uname -r)
KSRC=/lib/modules/$(KVER)/build
KGSPCADIR=/lib/modules/$(KVER)/kernel/drivers/media/video/gspca

all: modules

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD)/build modules

gspca_%::
    $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD)/build gspca_main.ko $@

install:
    rm -f $(KGSPCADIR)/gspca*.ko $(KGSPCADIR)/*/gspca*.ko \
            $(KGSPCADIR)/gspca*.gz $(KGSPCADIR)/*/gspca*.gz; \
    install -c -m 0644 build/*.ko $(KGSPCADIR)/; \
    depmod

# local development
dist:
    ln -s . gspca-$(VERSION); \
    files=`ls gspca-$(VERSION)/build/*.c | fgrep -v .mod.c`; \
    tar -zcvf gspca-$(VERSION).tar.gz \
            gspca-$(VERSION)/Makefile \
            gspca-$(VERSION)/README \
            gspca-$(VERSION)/build/Makefile \
            gspca-$(VERSION)/build/gspca.h.orig \
            gspca-$(VERSION)/build/*.h \
            $$files; \
    rm gspca-$(VERSION)
.PHONY: dist driver install update modules
```

I'm not sure what is going on. What does this error mean?

Comment: Are you aware that `/lib/modules/3.6.11+/build` should be a link to the 3.6.11+ kernel source tree?

Comment: @goldilocks I do not, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: see my answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

`/lib/modules/NN.NN.NN/build` is conventionally a soft link to the kernel source tree used to build the modules (often `/usr/src/linux-NN.NN.NN`).  *[The 'N' there and in the rest of this post means an actual version number, not a literal N.]*

It would appear you are using 3.6.11+ ?  **Make SURE this is the case.**

```
uname -r
```

If it's actually 3.2.27+, then use that source below.  If it really is 3.6.11+, I'm curious as to how you ended up with that (since having a used source tree may save you a lot of time and I don't think anything ships with it pre-compiled).

Anyway, if you don't have such a tree, you can download a "clean" one:

- [3.2.27](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/archive/rpi-3.2.27.tar.gz)
- [3.6.11](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/archive/rpi-3.6.y.tar.gz)

I copied these links from [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#Get_the_kernel_source). I've used the 3.6.11 on the pi so they should be good.  Put the tarball in `/usr/src` and extract:

```
tar -xzf rpi-3.[N.N].tar.gz
```

Now, if the directory created is "rpi-3.2.27":

```
rm /lib/modules/3.2.27/build
rm /lib/modules/3.2.27/src
ln -s /usr/src/3.2.27 /lib/modules/3.2.27/build
ln -s /usr/src/3.2.27 /lib/modules/3.2.27/src
```

This creates the link needed to access the kernel source to build your module. Unfortunately, this might involve building various kernel bits.  You need to include the current kernel config:<sup>1</sup>

```
cp /proc/config.gz /usr/src/[name of source directory]/
cd /usr/src/[directory]
gunzip config.gz
mv config .config
```

Now you can try your module build.  As mentioned, this will involve building bits in the source tree. I used a cross-compiler on a desktop to build a kernel for the pi, but I suspect if you have to do it on the pi itself this could take a long time -- like dinner, a movie, and take the long way home time.  So, if you do have a 3.6.11 tree around that you've already used to build your current kernel, use that instead, since it will contain any relevant bits and pieces.

---

<sup>1.  If you can't find `/proc/config.gz`, try `sudo modprobe configs` and look again.</sup>

Comment: Awesome, can't wait to try this at home today. I have no idea how I got 3.6.11+, I've run a lot of various linux commands from various websites on this PI. That is just the version number my pi says when I log in from SSH.

Answer (score 3):

We had the very same problem, and it turned out that '$(PWD)/build' directory, '/lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/build' on my laptop, is empty, but this build folder must be a shortcut of '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic' directory, therefore we built such shortcut manually and finally it started working perfectly.

- note: linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic is my kernel's header's name!
- you must have linux-headers installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ensure you have the kernel headers installed in the device, you can check using `ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)` , if you don't see any files in the output you need toinstall the rpi headers for the kernel. You can download it using `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`.

If you already have the the said headers installed you can try reinstlling that by `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers --reinstall`

Even if that doesn't work you need to see if the folder is a symlink to the other folder and follow the instructions to create a symlink to the actual location of the headers

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days in this problem.
I had to upgrade the OS using this [link](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/upgrade-raspberry-pi-os-to-bullseye-from-buster)

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y 
sudo rpi-update 
sudo apt update sudo apt
dist-upgrade
```